# Question on calculating probability of specific items from multiple number of items

Tags: probability

There is a lighting that has failure rate of 0.05/hour.
Total of 8 lightings are installed on a car.
Two on the front-right, two on the front-left, two on the rear-right and two on the rear-left. All have the same failure rate.

I'd think the probability of any 2 lightings to fail at the same time (one specific hour) is $0.05^2 = 0.0025$ per hour.

Whats confusing me is what the probability would be for the two (2) specific lightings to fail at the same time (one specific hour).
For example, what is the probability of the two front-right lightings to fail at the same time (one specific hour)?

I don't think its as simple as $0.05^2$.

Comment: The probability that any two lights fail at the *exact same time* is zero, for the same reason that the probability that two independent continuous random variables are equal is zero.

Comment: Hi math1000, I don't fully understand how the probablity can be zero? Could you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: The wording "failure rate of 0.05/hour" suggests that the time to failure of a light is exponentially distributed with rate $1/20$. Assuming the lights are independent of each other, the probability that they fail at the *exact* same time is zero, since the probability that two independent continuous random variables are equal is zero. If you do not understand why that is the case, I suggest you review your notes/textbook.

Comment: Thanks Math1000. I shouldve mentioned that the definition of "same time" is at one specific hour. In that case, the probablitiy wouldn't be 0, correct?

Comment: Yes, that completely changes the problem. I recommend you edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be clear whether the $0.05$/hour is intended to be the chance that one specific light fails or that one of the eight lights fails.  Even if it is one of the eight that means you have a failure about every $20$ hours, which is terrible.

If the $0.05/$hour is per light the chance that two specific lights fail in a particular hour is then $0.05^2$.

If the $0.05$/hour is for the whole set you need to translate that to the chance that an individual light fails in one hour.  You have $0.95$ chance that all eight survive the hour, so $0.95^{1/8}\approx 0.9936$ chance that any given one survives and $0.0064$/hour failure rate of one light.  The chance that two specific lights fail in one hour is the square of that.

Comment: Thanks Ross. 0.05/hr is for one specific light to fail. So if I want to know the probablitiy of two Front-Right lights to fail at the same time, its 0.05^2  = 0.0025/hr

Comment: Yes, it is, if by same time you mean within one specific hour.  They won't fail at exactly the same time.

Comment: thats right, at one specific hour. Thank you